# .net core appsettings in azure with objects

Tags: azure

I know this will be simple.
I have my **appsettings.json** file in my project which looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=sxp_identity;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Options": {
    "IdentityServerBaseUrl": "https://localhost:44362/",
    "AllowedOrigins": "http://localhost:4200,https://localhost:44384"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I want to override these, but I have just realised this is not the same as in none core applications because the options I want to change are in the **options** object.
Because in azure appsettings are key/value. How can I replicate this options object? Bearing in mine in the **Startup.cs** I do this:

```
services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("Options"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the way to do this was using the path with . notations, so for the connection string above an appsetting should be created with the name:

```
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString
```

Then set it's value normally.

Answer (score 0):

To override settings in Key Vault you use the following syntax for the secret name:

```
ConnectionStrings--ConnectionString
```

Then set the secret value to whatever value you want. 
So separate sections with double dash --.

Ultimately in Core the configuration is a set of keys and values. 
So when you specify a value override, it won't affect the rest of the object in appsettings.json.